# Cannot resolve method ' ' in 'T

Tags: java

У меня есть класс:

```
public class PurchasesList<T> {
    private T[] list;

    PurchasesList() {
        list = (T[]) new Object[1];
    }

    public void add(T object) {
        int index = find();

        if (index == -1) {
            increaseSizeArray();
            index = find();
        }

        list[index] = object;
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        return list[index];
    }

    public int size() {
        return list.length;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        boolean empty = false;
        for (T t : list) {
            empty = t == null;
        }
        return empty;
    }

    private void increaseSizeArray() {
        T[] temp = list;
        list = (T[]) new Object[list.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, list, 0, temp.length);
    }

    private int find() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i] == null) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Он предназначен для хранения экземляров класса:

```
public class Food {
    String product;
    double price;

    Food(String product, double price) {
        this.product = product;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Таких классов несколько; они однотипны, разница лишь в именах (Clothes, Entertainment, Other).

```
 private final PurchasesList<Food> food = new PurchasesList<>();
 private final PurchasesList<Clothes> clothes = new PurchasesList<>();
 private final PurchasesList<Entertainment> entertainment = new PurchasesList<>();
 private final PurchasesList<Other> other = new PurchasesList<>();
```

Я хочу создать метод, который будет проводить итерацию над элементами массива.

```
private <T> void show(PurchasesList<T> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            T elem = list.get(i);
            System.out.printf("%s $%s\n", elem.getProduct(), elem.getPrice());
        }
    }
```

Вопрос в том, как мне в метод передать, какой класс, я буду итерировать. В данном случае как я показал выше, я не имею доступа к  `getProduct()` и `getPrice()`:

```
(Cannot resolve method 'getProduct' in 'T', Cannot resolve method 'getPrice' in 'T')
```

Я думал, что доступ до этих методов можно реализовать через интерфейс, но у меня ничего не получилось.

Если я укажу напрямую, какой класс буду использовать, все работает.

```
for (int i = 0; i < food.size(); i++) {
    Food elem = food.get(i);
    System.out.printf("%s $%s\n", elem.getProduct(), elem.getPrice());
}
```

Я надеюсь, что достаточно подробно описал проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь интерфейсом, где нужно определить методы, используемые везде, т.е. `getProduct()` и `getPrice()`:

```
public interface Purchase {
    String getProduct();
    double getPrice();
}
```

Получается, что все классы товаров имплементируют интерфейс:

```java
public class Food implements Purchase {
    String product;
    double price;
    ...
}
```

```
public class Entertainment implements Purchase {
    String product;
    double price;
    ...
}
```

Далее хорошо бы ограничить возможность помещения объектов в `PurchasesList`, которые не имплементируют покупку, таким образом:

```java
public class PurchasesList<T extends Purchase> { ...
```

```java
private static <T extends Purchase> void show(PurchasesList<T> list) { ...
```

И не забудьте поменять `​(T[]) new Object[1]` на `(T[]) new Purchase[1]`

В итоге:

- у вас заработает конструкция

  ```
  T elem = list.get(i);
  elem.getProduct(), elem.getPrice()
  ```
- Вы ограничите товары, которые могут быть помещены в список покупок. В методе `show()` конструкция `<T extends Purchase>` сообщает о том, что сюда придут объекты, у которых точно будут методы `getProduct()` и `getPrice()`.